# Как манипулировать пикселями изображения на js?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, изображения, png

Делаю игру. Есть один `canvas`. На нем каждый кадр рисуются изображения в несколько слоев. Изображения `png` с прозрачностью. Мне нужно, к примеру, сделать одно из изображений ярче или увеличить контрастность. Как получить доступ к пикселям? `getImageData()` не помогает, т. к. он вырезает квадрат из холста, а мои изображения имеют не квадратную форму. Т.е. так я вырежу изображение и кусок изображения на заднем плане. Возможно ли как-то манипулировать пикселями `Image` до отрисовки на холсте?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение в пререндеринге на втором невидимом канвасе. Создаю второй канвас, рисую на нем картинку, забираю дату картинки, редактирую, рисую опять, а затем рисую на главном канвасе второй канвас.